# One view does not rerender when @State var changes based on Picker selection

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

Trying to build a simple MacOS app using SwiftUI.  I have a View that contains a Picker bound to a State var.  As a sanity check I have added a Text Views (the dwarves one and the volumes...itemName) that should also change with the Picker changes.  And they do, but the View I want to rerender (the FileList) does not.

I suspect it has something to do with how I am trying to pass the new FileSystemItem (internal class) to the FileList. Like when the FilePanel rerenders the volumeSelection is back to 0 and the state is applied afterwards.  So my problem is that I seem to be missing a fundamental concept on how this data is supposed to flow. I have gone through the WWDC info again and been reading other articles but I am not seeing the answer.

The desired behavior is changing the selection on the picker should cause a new FileSystemItem to be displayed in the FileList view.  What is the right way to get this to happen?  To state it more generically, how to you get a child view to display new data when a Picker selection changes?

```
struct FilePanel: View 
{
    @State var volumeSelection = 0
    @State var pathSelection = 0

    var volumes = VolumesModel() //should be passed in?
    var dwarves = ["Schlumpy","Wheezy","Poxxy","Slimy","Pervy","Drooly"]

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(selection: $volumeSelection, label:
                Text("Volume")
                , content: {
                    ForEach (0 ..< volumes.count()) {
                        Text(self.volumes.volumeAtIndex(index: $0).itemName).tag($0)
                    }
            })

            FileList(item:volumes.volumeAtIndex(index: volumeSelection)).frame(minWidth: CGFloat(100.0), maxHeight: .infinity)
            Text(dwarves[volumeSelection])
            Text(volumes.volumeAtIndex(index: volumeSelection).itemName)

        }
    }
 }

struct FileList: View {
    @State var item : FileSystemItem

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
        List(item.childItems){fsi in
            FileCell(expanded:false, item: fsi)
        }
        Text(item.itemName)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i would like to help, but i cannot "just copy" your code and run it, it is no fun... :(

Comment: Its not an issue where its what happens when the code runs. The behavior is described in the question. The question is about what is the right way in SwiftUI to accomplish pushing the new value (or making it available) to the child view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@State` is a state private to to the owning view, `FileList` will never see any change.

If `VolumesModel` was a simple struct turning `FileList.item` into a binding (in-out-state) may already work (the caller still needs to turn it's `@State` into a binding when passing it to the dependent using the `$`):

```
struct FileList: View {
  @Binding var item : FileSystemItem
  ...
}
```

However, it feels as if `VolumesModel` was a more complex object having an array of members.

If this is the case the above will not suffice:

- `VolumesModel` needs to be a class adopting `ObservableObject`
- `VolumesModel`'s important members need a bindable wrapper (`@Published`)
- `FileList.item` should be turned into `@ObservedObject` (instead of @State or @Binding)
- `FilePanel.volumes` also to be `@ObservedObject` wrapped

Hope that helps or at least points you into the right direction.

Comment: I figured something like that was going on with @State so thanks for the confirmation.  I had been looking at ObservableObject but it seemed like it was kind of overkill for the (seemingly) simple thing I am trying to accomplish. But I guess it is something I should pursue.  Thanks for the advice,  I appreciate it!

Comment: You were correct that the @State in FileList was wrong.  You also got me to look at ObservableObject which I think in the long run is what I need.  Thanks!